# Generate Random values X

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe and want to replace Unique Id's from Column "X" with unique digit random number from specific column in pandas dataframe.

```
Index   X
0   12345
1   12345
2   12347
3   12348
4   12347
5   12350
6   12351
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `factorize`

```
df['newid'] = df.ID.factorize()[0]+100000
Out[318]: 
array([100000, 100000, 100001, 100002, 100001, 100003, 100004],
      dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that works with *random* new ids:

```
# get the unique values and indexes
unique,idx = np.unique(df['ID'], return_inverse=True)

# new random key
random_keys = np.random.choice(np.arange(1_000_000, 9_999_999+1), size=len(unique), replace=False)

df['new_ID'] = random_keys[idx]
```

Or similar idea with `factorize`:

```
enum = df['ID'].factorize()[0]

random_keys = np.random.choice(np.arange(1_000_000, 9_999_999+1), size=enum.max()+1, replace=False)

df['new_ID'] = random_keys[enum]
```